# Is this gas fee calculation correct?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

An address consumes 20,000 gas via SSTORE.
Given is a gas price of 35 Gwei.

If I store 10,000 addresses in a map, it will cost me:
20,000 gas * 10,000 = 200,000,000 gas

200,000,000 Gas * 35 Gwei = 7 Ether.

Is the calculation correct?
If I do the same on a layer2 chain, does the whole thing cost me 7 matic for example, or is there something else I need to consider?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation is correct.

I'm assuming you want to store the values in an array instead of 10k separate storage variables. If it's a dynamic-length array, you should also consider the cost of `sstore` while updating a (non-zero to non-zero) value of the slot holding the array length (currently 2900 gas for each `.push()` function resizing the array).

You should also consider the block gas limit - a transaction costing 200M gas is not going to fit into a block on probably any network, so any miner won't mine it.

So based on your use case, you might want to change the approach. For example, if the addresses are used for validation, you might be able to store just the [merkle tree](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/merkle-tree/) root (1 value instead of the 10k) and then validate against it using the address and its merkle proof.

Comment: Hi Petr, thanks for your detailed answer!
In this case, there is no use case at all. My goal was to hypothetically approximate the price to figure out the break-even for implementing off-chain storage via a Merkle tree.